# ThreeJS TrackballControls get mouse click from constrctor

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I need to get the mouse click event inside my java-script code to perform some action,

Right now I am creating the event listener using TrackballControls

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera,webglEl);
```

And how can get a call back when mouse click happens, I have to call another function when mouse click happens.

Comment: Have you tried adding your own click listener to the canvas?

Comment: Yes I solved it in that way.